# file in use after sending email with attachment

Tags: c#, smtp

I am sending a file through .net's smtp as such:

```
private void SendMail()
{
  var _msg = new MailMessage();
  const string cEmailUsername = "xxxxxx";
  const string cEmailPassword = "zzzzzz";
  const string cSmtpClient = "yyyyyyy";

  try
  {
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(cSmtpClient))
    {
      _msg.From = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.CompanyEmailAddress)
                    ? new MailAddress(cEmailUsername)
                    : new MailAddress(Configuration.CompanyEmailAddress.ToLower());
      _msg.Subject = string.Format("Request for .Net Support - {0} - {1}", Configuration.CompanyID,
                                   Configuration.GetCompanyName());
      _msg.Body = string.Format("Propane.exe date: {0}{1}{1}{2}", Configuration.VersionDate, Environment.NewLine,
                                "Check parsing log file attached.");
      _msg.To.Add("eric@suburbansoftware.com");
      _msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_logFile));

      var cred2 = new NetworkCredential(cEmailUsername, cEmailPassword);
      smtp.Port = 587;
      smtp.Credentials = cred2;
      smtp.Timeout = 0;
      smtp.Send(_msg);
    }

    var oldfile = _logFile + ".old";
    if (File.Exists(oldfile))
    {
      File.Delete(oldfile);
    }
    File.Move(_logFile,oldfile);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    richTextBox_Message.Text += ex.Message;
  }
}
```

I am getting a file in use exception when I get to the file.move. If I comment out the using portion, the move works just fine.

Is there a way around this or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Try giving the OS a second or two to close the file handle and see if the problem goes away (if so you might need to add some retry logic to your code)

Comment: k I'll sleep it and try it out thx for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Using` works just with `smtp`, not with `_msg`. This variable is the one containing the attachment and is not disposed. Include this code right after finishing the `using` part and everything should be fine:

```
_msg.Dispose();
_msg = null;
```

Comment: MailMessage implements IDisposable so you could just nest your using statements if your wanted, just place this right under your first using statement.  using(var _msg = new MailMessage())